# Non-monadic adjunction

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

Could someone give some examples of a non-monadic adjunctions please? Possibly explaining why they are not monadic and how they contradict the monadicity theorem?
Thanks!

Comment: [According to nlab, the category of cancellative monoids provides an example](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category). Explicitly, the adjunction consists of the usual forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$, and its left-adjoint, which builds the usual free monoid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A classical example : the forgetful functor from topological spaces to sets.

The left adjoint is the "discrete space" functor (sending a set $X$ to the discrete space with underlying space $X$), and the composition just gives the identity on Sets, so clearly Top is not the Eilenberg-Moore category of the monad.

You can see that the forgetful functor does not reflect isomorphisms (a homeomorphism is more than a bijective continuous function), so the monadicity theorem indeed cannot be applied.

Comment: Good one! This is a nice and intuitive example. And it emphasizes an important phenomenon, which is that our adjunctions tend to be monadic iff we're doing algebra.

Comment: And magically, as soon as you pass to the spaces (compact Hausdorff) where $U$ *does* reflect isomorphisms, you have a monadic adjunction! Though not with the discrete space functor, of course.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but it could give you a little insight on what *monadic* really means.

Given a monad $(T,\eta,\mu)$ on a category $\mathcal C$, you can form the *category $\operatorname{Adj}(\mathcal C,T)$ of adjunctions above $T$*:

- its objects are the ajdunction $F: \mathcal C \rightleftarrows \mathcal D :U$ ($F$ on the left) such that the induced monad $(UF,{\rm unit},U\,{\rm counit}\,F)$ equals $(T,\eta,\mu)$ ;
- a morphism from $F: \mathcal C \rightleftarrows \mathcal D :U$ to $F': \mathcal C \rightleftarrows \mathcal D' :U'$ is a functor $K \colon \mathcal D \to \mathcal D'$ such that $KF = F'$, $U'K = U$ and $K$ commutes with counits.

This category $\operatorname{Adj}(\mathcal C,T)$ has a **terminal object**: the Eilenberg-Moore category of $T$. The unique morphism from any other object is the so called *comparison* functor. Hence, by definition, a adjunction $F: \mathcal C \rightleftarrows \mathcal D :U$ is monadic if and only if it is terminal in $\operatorname{Adj}(\mathcal C,UF)$.

It should make you realize that, in a sense, most adjunctions are non-monadic. For example, the previous category $\operatorname{Adj}(\mathcal C,T)$ always have an **initial object**: the Kleisli category of $T$. And this category is terminal only if every algebra over $T$ is free! Which is quite uncommon. It produces a lot of examples of non-monadic adjunctions $$Set \rightleftarrows \text{Free algrebas over T}$$
for $T$ the monad of groups, monoids, modules over a non-field ring, etc.

---

Note that the initial and terminal object can be the same (as in the example of Captain Lama), but still leaving some "room" for non monadic adjunctions in between.